# Why is log in via Stack Exchange OpenID so complicated?

Tags: support, login, openid

I want to use one dedicated account for and only for all the OpenExchange sites. That means I don't want to use third-party login methods like Google or Facebook.

For this reason I have created an OpenID account on Stack Exchange OpenID. However, when you go to the login page, there is no option for this login method. You have to click on "more login options" and then copy paste a special OpenID link that you can find on your SE OpenID account details page.

Why isn't logging via Stack Exchange's OpenID service more friendly?

For example, there could be button like "Login via Stack Exchange OpenID".

Comment: Have you tried on a different network site? Because **usually** when you go to a site and you're already logged in on the network, you're not given the option to use anything else, just a button for "join this site". Every now and then (rarely) it breaks and doesn't recognize your OpenID... is it possible that's the problem here? Can you show us a screenshot of the page you're on?

Comment: What is "OpenExchange sites"?

Comment: The one situation where you *actually* have to do this is when you *unlinked* your SE open ID from an account and need to link it again. Otherwise its just username and password as enjoli and Adam have suggested. My secondary account uses a + notation gmail account with a password and it works fine, except when I forget the password ;p

Comment: @PeterMortensen There is list of the sites: https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: @Catija As you have written - you have to be logged at least on one site, but what if I am not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The email/password fields are the Stack Exchange OpenID credentials. We optimized the UI for the majority of people who neither know nor particularly care about what OpenID is.

So, no need to click "more options" and paste anything in, just punch in your email and password and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Actually, that's really not obvious. I had no idea those fields are for Stack Exchange OpenID for long years, thinking they're meant to log in using whatever email provider I have.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard Where did I say it was obvious?

Comment: You didn't, but I wanted to link to feature request asking to make it clearer... just can't find it.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard Fair enough. At this point, though, introducing (what I personally think would be) "technically correct" clarifications would likely only cause more confusion for all the people who have signed up with an email/password in the past... uh... 3 or 4 years? I forget when this change went in, exactly.

Comment: What I suggest is as simple as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0mZr.png). Pretty sure I've already suggested this somewhere... maybe it got downvoted and auto nuked by now.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard That does sound familiar. Now... imagine you just signed up. Suddenly there's something called "Stack Exchange OpenID"? Where did your normal email and password field go? This boat has sailed, IMO.

Comment: I didn't know that I can use OpenID credentials there. Now it makes sense but maybe it would be better to have a mention about this possibility on the login page.

Comment: @Adam well, one has to start learning somewhere... :-)

Answer (score 0):

A screenshot is attached for visual people.

- Go to stackexchange.com
- Click *Log in* at the top right
- Select the Stack Exchange Logo (instead of the third-party logins)
- Enter Email & password to authenticate.

Many Thanks to [Peter Mortensen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/63550/peter-mortensen) for editorial assistance & [doppelgreener](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152515/doppelgreener) for visual artistry =)

[image]

Comment: er, no need to delete and repost, you can always edit your own posts. Considering the other one is a +1, *undeleting that* , editing it and deleting this one makes so much more sense.

Comment: Deleted and reposted for user disassociation not editorial purposes. Thank you for your due care. Social Points are not my personal motivator.